# Sending amazon uploaded file as an attachment in smtp client c#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, smtp

I have uploaded a file on amazon bucket.

How can i send that file as an attachment using `SmtpClient` in c#.

**Below is my code snippet**

```
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

 msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("https://......."));
 client.Send(msg);
```

**it throws an exception says url is not supported.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attached the amazon files by getting the file's Steam by downloading though making Httprequest and then attached in to email object asynchronously.